# NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to compile main class in Java program, while all resources are imported

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, compilation

I'm creating a small app to send messages to phone numbers using google voice. I made a simple test case that works in Eclipse and can send out messages as expected. However, when I try to run it on a terminal, I keep running into issues. Here is the main class I've written:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.techventus.server.voice.Voice;

public class main_WUB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String username = "wake.up.bot.acc";
    String password = "wakeupbotacc";
    String originNumber = #;
    String pavlePhone = #;
    String wakeupMessage = "txt from main_WUB";


    try {
        Voice voice = new Voice(username, password);
        voice.sendSMS(pavlePhone, wakeupMessage);
        System.out.println("IT WORKED?");

        //voice.call(originNumber, pavlePhone, "1");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I've transferred the class into a remote server to test on a linux machine, however, these are the issues I've come up against. When I try to run the main class using

```
java main_WUB
```

it returns an exception, stating

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/techventus/server/voice/Voice at main_WUB.main<main_WUB.java:18> ...
```

What confuses me is that I ran into this error beforehand in eclipse, and fixed it by importing the reference library in which com.techventus.server.voice.Voice is contained. Now I'm running into the same issue when trying to compile directly. Is there a way to fix this? What am I missing in my command? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a jar file for your entire project in eclipse. Procedure for making jar file in eclipse -> right click on your project -> export -> java -> runnable jar file -> select main_WUB in launch configuration drop down list box -> select radio button "extract required libraries into generated jar" -> finish.

now open cmd promt -> goto the path where jar is there -> then give the command "java -jar main_WUB"

It should work.

Comment: When attempting to do this, I get a set of warnings from Eclipse, stating that the .project and .classpath entries are duplicated. When I then try to run it from command line, I get an error saying the jar cannot be accessed.

Comment: First of all you can ignore warnings. "Jar cannot be accessed means" your path is not correct in command prompt. Go to the correct command prompt where the jar files resides in then enter your command.

Comment: Works perfectly now! One of the major barriers for completion is overcome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need build the JAR with all Libs (dependences) includes.

When you build your project in Eclipse, use the option 'Build with dependences'